# During doing h,w with Java, an error about String range has raised

Tags: java

I made the codes for a credit card tester. while I compile these codes, it has been compiled successfully. however, when I enter 12 digits of credit card numbers, it showed a message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 11. I would really appreciate it if you guys tell me what has been wrong on the codes. Thank you

```
  public class CreditCard{
    
    private String cardNumber; //The credit card number is stored as String.
    private boolean valid; //To indicate valid or not
    int errorCode; //instance variable 
    
    
// initializing instance variables
    public CreditCard(String creditCardNumber){
        cardNumber = creditCardNumber;  
        valid = true; //initial instance = true, assumes that inputted numbers can be false 
        errorCode = 0;
      } 
      
    public void check1(){
        //The first digit must be a 4.
        if(cardNumber.charAt(0) != 4){
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 1; //case 1 error 
            return;
        }
    }

    public void check2(){
        //The fourth digit must be one greater than the fifth digit  int fourth = Integer.parseInt(4,5)
        int fourth = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(4,5));
        int fifth = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(5,6));
        if(fourth != fifth + 1){
            
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 2;
            return;
        }
    }
        
    public void check3(){
        //The product of the first, fifth, and ninth digits must be 24
        int first = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(1,2));
        int fifth = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(5,6));
        int ninth = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(9,10));
        if(first * fifth * ninth != 24){
            
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 3;
            return;
        }
    }
    public void check4(){
        //The sum of all digits must be evenly divisible by 4
        int sum = 0; //initiate variable sum
        for(int i=0; i<cardNumber.length(); i++  )
        sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue(cardNumber.charAt(i));
        if(sum % 4 != 0){
            
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 4;
            return;
        }
    }
    public void check5(){
        // The sum of the first four digits must be one less than the sum of the last four digits
        int sumFirst = 0;
        int sumLast = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<4; i++)
            sumFirst = sumFirst + Character.getNumericValue(cardNumber.charAt(i));
        for(int i = 0, j = cardNumber.length(); i<4; i++, j-- )
            sumLast = sumLast + Character.getNumericValue(cardNumber.charAt(j));
        if(sumFirst != sumLast - 1){
            
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 5;
            return;
        }
            
    }
        
    public void check6(){
        //If you treat the first two digits as a two-digit number, and the seventh and eight digits as a two digit number, their sum must be 100. 
        int first = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(0,2));
        int seight = Integer.parseInt(cardNumber.substring(8,10));
        if(first + seight != 100){
            
            valid = false;
            errorCode = 6;
            return;
        }
    }
      
        
    public void check(){
        check1();
        check2();
        check3();
        check4();
        check5();
        check6();
    }
    
    public boolean isValid(){
        
        return valid;
    }    
    
    
    public int getErrorCode(){
    
        return errorCode; 
      }
}
```

Comment: You need to add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when u get length of string its array of chars start from zero and end in length-1;

in your fifth check you accessed the char at index j that basically is outside of range of string array

Comment: Your advice helped a lot. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi besides the Index Out of Bound Error, I think you missed something in the check1() method.

If the cardNumber is stored as string, the line `if(cardNumber.charAt(0) != 4){` should be `if(cardNumber.charAt(0) != '4'){` as it's checking the character instead of int.